# Mysql date and rails dates with utc

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We want to get all the people that are born on a certain date. For the moment we use the query like this :

```
User.where(["day(birthdate) = day(?) AND month(birtdate) = month(?)", Time.now.utc, Time.now.utc ])
```

Now when we safe a user with date 29/03/1989 in the form, the field birthdate in the db contains this : 28/03/1989 22:00:00 UTC+2

The problem is that mysql will take 28 as day instead of 29 when we use the day() function of mysql.

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349280/storing-datetime-as-utc-in-php-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of MySQL data type do you use to store the birthday attribute? It probably helps to store only the date (not the time) by choosing the data type `date` instead of `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is helpful to set the right time zone in environment.rb (Rails 2.x) or application.rb (Rails 3.x), for example config.time_zone = "Europe/Berlin"? Active Record should auto-convert the time to this zone.

Comment: Indeed, but if the date is 28/03/1989 22:00:00 UTC+2 in the DB, then the mysql function day(28/03/1989 22:00:00 UTC+2) will give back 28 and activerecord day(Time.now) 29 if we are 28/03/1989 22:00:00 UTC+2