# Strange javascript Date toISOString

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, timestamp

I am using fullcalendar for a project of mine. I have a strange problem that keeps bugging me. When I export an event, I want to get it in timestamp format, which is OK. the problem is when I try to convert it to ISO format using Date.toISOString function, it gives me the time 2 hours earlier. I think it is a problem of my timezone, because I posted my timestamp on `http://www.unixtimestamp.com/` and it gives me the right time, but when I do it in my browser, it gives me the date and time with 2 hours earlier. I can't seem to figure it out. I googled a lot  for a solution, but nothing so far. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Please show some code so we can see what you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

`toISOString` will give you a string to represent the time in **UTC**. If you look at the result closely enough, you can find there is a "Z" in the end, which means the timezone is UTC.

Comment: OK, I looked up to it. But how cand I get my result? Because I want to insert the date in a string format into mysql via php.

Comment: @user2435860 a quick search give me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349280/storing-datetime-as-utc-in-php-mysql

Comment: @user2435860 You need to give us more information. What column type are you using to store the date in mysql? DATETIME or TIMESTAMP? Do you store the date in UTC or local time? How do you use the result of `toISOString`, to display or send to server?