# Converting String to Date is off by a Day

Tags: mysql, sql, date

When I try to convert a string to a date in MYSQL, I'm getting weird results.

```
SELECT 
    '2017-06-20' d
    ,CAST('2017-06-20' as DATE) d1
    ,DATE_FORMAT('2017-06-20', '%Y-%m%-%d') d2 
    ,STR_TO_DATE('2017-06-20', '%Y-%m-%d') d3
    ,DATE('2017-06-20') d4
```

On my machine, d2 is the only correct date, i.e. it generates `2017-06-20`.  The rest, i.e. d1, d3 and d4, generate `06/19/2017`.  Why?  I'm especially perplexed by `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this finding.

Comment: Possible dup / explanation... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774904/why-is-my-date-from-mysql-decrementing-by-one-day-in-javascript

Comment: What version of mysql, and what are your time zone settings?

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone';`

Comment: MY SQL Version: 5.7.12

Comment: System time Zone: UTC

Comment: This had to do with Toad, the editor I was using.  For some, it was displaying a different time than what was actually in the database.  Not sure why an editor would do this, but be weary of Toad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused about data types.  MySQL has built-in data types.  It will recognize `'YYYY-MM-DD'` as a string.

When the result of an expression is a string, it is put into the result set as-is.

When the result is a date/time, then it is shown based on your local settings.

So, `DATE_FORMAT()` is interpreting the first argument as a date and converting it to a string.  That is what you get.

On the other hand, `STR_TO_DATE()` does what the name implies.  It converts the first argument -- a string -- to a date.  That is then presented based on your local settings.