# Converting to UTC Calendar instance in Joda-Time

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jpa, jodatime

I am using Joda-Time API for managing date and time in my web application.
I have a method which converts the milliseconds to `Calendar` object.

```java
public static synchronized Calendar getUTCCalenderInstance( final Long millisecondsTime )
{
    return new DateTime(millisecondsTime).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toGregorianCalendar();
}
```

And I am saving it in MySQL database using `spring-data-jpa`. But when viewed in database, it is storing the timestamp in current local timezone. How to fix this issue?

My `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?
useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
```

My Java entity is:

```java
@Entity
@Table( name = "task" )
@Data
public class TaskModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
@Column( name = "t_id" )
private Long id;

@Column( name = "t_name" )
private String taskName;

@Column( name = "t_description" )
private String taskDescription;

@Column( name = "t_start_date" )
private Calendar startDate;

@Column( name = "t_due_date" )
private Calendar dueDate;

@Column( name = "t_created_at" )
private Calendar createdAt;
```

Comment: You should provide more information to your question, like what is the data type you are using for your date column on the table. For your case, are you using `DATETIME` as format? That might be it. 
See:
 
How to store a datetime in MySQL with timezone info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846739/2408863
Docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html
and:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No, I am using TIMESTAMP as data type in DB

Comment: If changing data type is not an issue, try `DATETIME` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: before involving JPA, kindly state what is your JPA entity, and what is the (Java) type of the field that is persisted, and whether it has the correct value before/after persist

Comment: The java data type is `java.util.Calendar` and added entity class in the update above

Comment: Please give a look to this [link](http://www.developerscrappad.com/228/java/java-ee/ejb3-jpa-dealing-with-date-time-and-timestamp/) too. It provides many solutions on how to represent datetime with or without location information when dealing with MySql and JPA. Hope it helps

Comment: so is the value in the field correct before persist? If so then the problem is nothing to do with Jodatime, and everything to how you persist it (JPA config and JPA provider). If not then the problem is your Jodatime conversion. aka debug it!