# Which mysql datatype is more suitable to store "21:08:40.774 UTC JUN 11 2016" data

Tags: java, mysql

I want to store the "21:08:40.774 UTC JUN 11 2016" data in mysql in DATE type column but DATE type is not compatible to store "21:08:40.774 UTC JUN 11 2016" such data.
It will be helpful if some one can suggest what kind of mysql data type I should use to store data like "21:08:40.774 UTC JUN 11 2016"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use two fields. One to store datetime value and another to store timezone

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843203/how-to-store-a-datetime-in-mysql-with-timezone-info

Comment: See also: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,269092

Comment: Are all your times in UTC, or can each time have its own time zone? Not that I know which difference it may make in MySQL in particular.

Comment: In any case I think you need to use a `datetime` or a `timestamp` column, not a `date` column.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for the approach but can we do this without doing this segregation? as that is the requirement

Comment: @OleV.V. Time zone is not hard coded ..it can be any time zone