# Column of type "Local Datetime" doesn't match with type "TIMESTAMP" in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, timestamp

I'm experiencing an issue of type compatibility in MySQL version 5.6.
I have this data formatted as `Local Date time` (2007-01-01T00:25:47) and I need to write them on database, but I cannot find a corresponding type compatible with MySQL.

I have already tried with:

- `DATETIME`
- `TIMESTAMP`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Timestamp should work may be the value that you are trying to get in is invalid

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the `T` in your `Local Date time` makes the value incompatible with MySQL's `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` columns. However you can work around that using either [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the format, or using [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to replace the `T` with a space (thus making it a MySQL compatible datetime). For example:

```
create table test (d datetime, t timestamp);
insert into test values 
(str_to_date('2007-01-01T00:25:47', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'), str_to_date('2007-01-01T00:25:47', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')),
(replace('2007-01-01T00:25:47', 'T', ' '),replace('2007-01-01T00:25:47', 'T', ' '));
select * from test
```

Output:

```
d                       t
2007-01-01 00:25:47     2007-01-01 00:25:47
2007-01-01 00:25:47     2007-01-01 00:25:47
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=913dd2485116c64e72f71a2f9040c400)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the MySQL command for parsing a string to a date?

```
STR_TO_DATE(str,format)
```

You could try converting your current type to a string, then pipe it though the STR_TO_DATE command to then be stored on your database in the correct format.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Bu there is now way for import the the type field "Local datetime" in MySQL?

Comment: I'm looking through the MySQL docs and there doesn't appear to be a "LocalDateTime" data type to store, however I found this link which could potentially be of use? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843203/how-to-store-a-datetime-in-mysql-with-timezone-info

Apologies if it it isn't, I'm not to sure what your use case is but if it doesn't work please let me know and I'll try to help further.