# Timezone issue Nodejs Sequalize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

In My current project, I am using Sequalize ORM with Mysql.
This is the timestamp I am passing to be stored in the database  `2022-03-14 12:50:57.519`

But after storing the data, it automatically gets converted to UTC
 `2022-03-14 07:20:57`

timedatectl output

```
           Universal time: Mon 2022-03-14 07:55:56 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2022-03-14 07:55:57
                Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Database timezone configuration

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: What exact tiype does a column have in DB?

Comment: Did you see that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846739/1376618 ? Is it related to your issue?