# Convert Javascript DateTime LocalTime To Mysql Datetime

Tags: javascript, react-native

What is the best way to convert local datetime to mysql datetime ?

example :

```
const date1 = new Date(1658483664000);
console.log(date1);
```

output :

```
Fri Jul 22 2022 16:54:24 GMT+0700 (WIB) // Get My Local Datetime
```

How do I turn it into mysql datetime :

```
2022-07-22 16:54:24
```

Thank You

Comment: Did you try `new Date().toISOString()` which should give you something like `2022-07-22T16:54:24+07:00`

Comment: new Date().toISOString() give another timezone. I want my local time (Indonesia). Also I want to convert it to Mysql Datetime

Comment: What time is it now where you are and what does the above give you? It's likely the same point in time.

Comment: new Date().toISOString() give me : 2022-07-22T11:42:29.803Z. My time now is Friday 22 July 18.43

Comment: Okay so, `2022-07-22T11:42:29.803Z`, `2022-07-22T18:42:29.803+0700` and `Friday 22 July 18.43` all represent the same point in time. These are effectively all the same.

Comment: Yes. this one : 2022-07-22T18:42:29.803+0700 is indonesia time, my location

Comment: Which is equivalent to the value you get! FYI - It is generally a good idea to save dates & times in databases using UTC not local time.

Comment: how do you get my localtime in this format 2022-07-22T18:42:29.803+0700 ? I cannot use UTC time, all my datetime is my local time. And I need to use this localtime for in app purchase

Comment: It ___IS___ the same time!

Comment: Related question: [How to store a datetime in MySQL with timezone info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843203/how-to-store-a-datetime-in-mysql-with-timezone-info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const date1 = new Date(1658483664000);
 var date =moment(date1 ).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

to use this code you need to include moment.js in your project
https://momentjs.com

Comment: Remove the comma, remove the am/pm marker and use 24 hour HH notation and that might actually work!

Comment: Also... the momentJS project is effectively deprecated and should not be used for new development.

Comment: I think i should use this one. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Moment.js is a fine library, but it is heavy and its maintainers consider it a legacy project. See [this page](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) for an explanation and a list of alternatives that the moment.js team suggests.

One thing to look into in native JavaScript is the [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) object, which allows you to format a Date in a highly customizable, locale-based format. You can choose locale formats that are close to what you're looking for and manipulate them to get the final desired result. For example,

```js
const date = new Date(Date.now());

const formatOptions = {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta', 
  dateStyle: 'short', 
  hour12: false, 
  timeStyle: 'medium'
};

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-CA',formatOptions).format(date).split(',').join(''));
// example output: "2022-07-24 04:29:31"
```

This relies on the fact that Canadians format their dates YYYY-MM-DD, for example. Additionally, the `split` and `join` are necessary because the formatter initially gives you "2022-07-24, 04:29:31"

Finally, if you have control over how these are written to the mysql database, you can use the [STR_TO_DATE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert any date string from a known format into a MySQL DATETIME value.

Comment: Must put => year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' and hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric' to show the time. I see this documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat