# Comparing time.Time out of MySQL with Before seems not working

Tags: datetime, go, time, timezone

I'm trying to compare two `time.Time` dates in Go using the `Before` function.
The issue is that one of these dates comes from a MySQL `datetime` field.

When I Scan the result, it is saved as a UTC timezone, but I wrote in database in my local time (UTC +1). This is a problem when I compare the database date with a `time.Now()` that is in my local time.

I extracted the date with a scan into a `time.Time` variable with `?parseTime=true` on the connection string.

Do you have any suggestion? I don't want to add 1 hour after reading the date from the DB because it can cause me problems with summer time (UTC +2).

I tried to extract the date from DB and convert with UTC function:

```
data, _ = time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", data.UTC().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
```

but without any success.

Comment: Related: [How to store a datetime in MySQL with timezone info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19843203/10197418)

Answer (score -2):

to convert a mysql datetime value to a Go time.Time correctly I recommend this code:

```
datesplit := strings.Split(mysql_datetime, " ")
rfc3339_datetime = datesplit[0] + "T" + datesplit[1] + "Z"
godate, _ = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, datetime)
```

Comment: datetime fields aren't guaranteed to represent UTC, so hard-coding a "Z" (= UTC) seems error-prone to me