# DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, mysql, java-time

I have a datetime column in mysql database (colum is called creation_date), everytime im going to save the entity that has that column I fill that column like so (it is a LocalDateTime in my java class):

```
public static LocalDateTime argDate() {
    return LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"));
}
```

So I need to make a calculation with that date, to check which records have certain conditions and one of those is if the time between the current date and that "creation_date" is equal or higher than **70 seconds**, do something with that, so I would like to **make sure I am working with only Argentina time** to have accurate results and no mistakes, so this works:

```
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(entity.getCreationDate(), argDate());
```

that method works, but I wanted to be 100% sure that I am working with Argentina date, so I tried this but **started getting the error in the title**:

```
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(entity.getCreationDate().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires")), argDate());
```

The thing is I have many questions right now, one is if the column type at Mysql will always give me back the datetime in Argentina time because since I am always saving it with that ZoneId, I would expect that to be that way...

And another one is how can I fix that error on the title? So I make sure I am working with Argentina time and the calculation of the seconds is good

So far I believe that my assumption that the Mysql datetime being in Argentina time is correct, because I decided to log some entries and this is the output:

```
LocalDateTime now = argDate();
log.info("database entity creation_date (arg): {}, now (arg): {}", entity.getCreationDate(), now);
```

Output:

```
database entity creation_date (arg): 2023-07-20T15:08:25, now (arg): 2023-07-20T15:09:24.013604344
```

But my fear is that maybe this is not true? And the timezone of the server of the database is argentina time luckyly? Or is it respecting the zoneId I gave it when saving it

**Research**:

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846739/12085680) I should not worry about this scenario, since it is a datetime column it will respect the zoneId I gave it before saving it (Argentina), so when I retrieve this from database it will already be in Arg time, but still curious of how to fix the error on title

Comment: What is the type `creation_date` column?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash in mysql it is type datetime and in my java model it is of type LocalDateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entity.getCreationDate().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"))` returns a `ZonedDateTime` and hence the error because then you are trying to find a difference between a `ZonedDateTime` and a `LocalDateTime`. Change it to

```
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(entity.getCreationDate(), argDate());
```

Since you are already storing `LocalDateTime` in your database, this will give you the difference between the two `LocalDateTime`s.

If you still want to use `entity.getCreationDate().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"))`, you need to change the definition of `argDate` to

```
public static ZonedDateTime argDate() {
    return ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"));
}
```

so that you can find the difference between two `ZonedDateTime`s.

Comment: Cool yes I was searching a bit, I should not worry because since im saving with the zoneId of argentina to the mysql databse, it is respecting this, but your proposal to change to ZonedDateTime is interesting, if I save to mysql database, it will still be valid for the datetime column?

Comment: *if I save to mysql database, it will still be valid for the datetime column?* - not without changing the column type in your DB . Please do check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573).

Comment: Another suggested reading is [this](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/support-for-date-time-types-in-connector-j-8-0/). Check here the section, **OffsetDateTime and ZonedDateTime support**.